# jquery is not loading when using require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am having trouble loading jquery with require.js

Here is the html script:

```
<script data-main="js/mainU.js" src="js/libs/require.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the mainU.js file

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    baseUrl: "libs",
    paths: {
        jquery: ["//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js",
         "jquery.min"],
        underscore: "underscore-amd.min",
        backbone: "backbone-amd.min"
    },

});

define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
    function ($, _, Backbone) {
        console.log("Test output");
        console.log("$: " + typeof $);
        console.log("_: " + typeof _);
        console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
    }
);
```

The files are in the correct folders

Comment: Neither [http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min) nor the [https](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min) variant are valid paths. They return a `404` eror. You probably mean [//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js), note the `js` at the end.

Comment: is it necessary for the require.js? and shouldn't my local file run anyways if the first link does not load, it still does not work and I added the error I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to not need the baseUrl, taking it away and just adding libs/ infront of the js files worked out.

So it looks like this now...

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    //baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        "jquery": ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min",
         "libs/jquery.min"],
        "underscore": "libs/underscore-amd.min",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-amd.min"
    }

});

define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
    function ($, _, Backbone) {
        console.log("Test output");
        console.log("$: " + typeof $);
        console.log("_: " + typeof _);
        console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are loading the jQuery from CDN , in which you are giving .js extension , remove the .js extension, it will work fine.